# Why there is a sudden drop in the training model of cnn?

Tags: conv-neural-network, training-data

Is there a reason why there is a short drop during the training model between epoch 150 to 250?[Training model Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPhp0.png)

Comment: I guess this is just an example.

Comment: what the reason could it be for the drop? I obtained this from my trained model, i assume its cause of overfitting of the model? is there any better reason could be?